# Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some Gesture'

Tags: ios, swift

In my view I have a ZStack with a text in it

```
Text(emoji.text)
    .gesture(isEmojiSelected(emoji: emoji) ? moveSelectedEmojis() : moveUnselectedEmoji(emoji: emoji))


    private func moveUnselectedEmoji(emoji: EmojiArt.Emoji) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($gestureEmojiMoveOffset) { … }
            .onEnded { … }
    }
    
    
    private func moveSelectedEmojis() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($gestureEmojiMoveOffset) { … }
            .onEnded { … }
    }
```

I get the compiler error on the .gesture ternary line above, which makes no sense to me because the funcs both return some Gesture:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some Gesture' (result of 'EmojiArtDocumentView.moveSelectedEmojis()') and 'some Gesture' (result of 'EmojiArtDocumentView.moveUnselectedEmoji(emoji:)’)

So:

I change it to this :

```
Text(emoji.text)    
    .gesture(moveEmojis(emoji: emoji))
```

```
And the func looks like this:
```

```
    
private func moveEmojis(emoji: EmojiArt.Emoji) -> some Gesture {
        if (selectedEmojis.count > 0 && isEmojiSelected(emoji: emoji)) {
            return moveSelectedEmojis()
        } else {
            return moveUnselectedEmoji(emoji: emoji)
        }
    }
```

I get this compiler error, which I don’t understand because both funcs are essentially identical

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'some Gesture' to return type 'AnyGesture'

I also tried making an exact copy of the function  name moveSelectedEmojis1 , to try and understand what is happening , but that does not compile either and gets the same error.

```
.gesture(isEmojiSelected(emoji: emoji) ? moveSelectedEmojis() :  moveSelectedEmojis1() )

private func moveSelectedEmojis() -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .updating($gestureEmojiMoveOffset) { latestDragGestureValue, gestureEmojiMoveOffset, transaction in
                print("gestureEmojiMoveOffset: \(gestureEmojiMoveOffset)")
                gestureEmojiMoveOffset = latestDragGestureValue.translation / self.zoomScale
            }
    .onEnded { finalDragGestureValue in
                //print("1steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset: \(steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset) ")
                self.steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset = self.steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset + (finalDragGestureValue.translation / self.zoomScale)
                print("steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset: \(steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset) ")
                var tmp: Set<EmojiArt.Emoji> = []
                for emoji in selectedEmojis {
                    document.moveEmoji(emoji, by: steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset)
                    tmp.insert(document.updateEmojiLocation(emoji, by: steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset))
                }
                selectedEmojis = tmp
                steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset = .zero
                print("moveended selected Emojis: \(selectedEmojis)")
            }
}
    
private func moveSelectedEmojis1() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($gestureEmojiMoveOffset) { latestDragGestureValue, gestureEmojiMoveOffset, transaction in
                print("gestureEmojiMoveOffset: \(gestureEmojiMoveOffset)")
                gestureEmojiMoveOffset = latestDragGestureValue.translation / self.zoomScale
            }
            .onEnded { finalDragGestureValue in
                //print("1steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset: \(steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset) ")
                self.steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset = self.steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset + (finalDragGestureValue.translation / self.zoomScale)
                print("steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset: \(steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset) ")
                var tmp: Set<EmojiArt.Emoji> = []
                for emoji in selectedEmojis {
                    document.moveEmoji(emoji, by: steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset)
                    tmp.insert(document.updateEmojiLocation(emoji, by: steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset))
                }
                selectedEmojis = tmp
                steadyStateEmojiMoveOffset = .zero
                print("moveended selected Emojis: \(selectedEmojis)")
            }
}
```

Comment: Use `AnyGesture` to type erase the gestures

Comment: Tried to use AnyGesture but ended up with run time error.  Any chance you can post a working sample?